# how call extenal api data and load it in view using node and angularjs.1.x - ngRoute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

i try to learn by practice by myself, but few attempts are failed.

could some tell me how to load external api to load it in view with ngRoute and Nodejs.?

below is my previous question, but no one has respond due to their busy schedule.

[SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48943986/faild-to-load-cross-origin-requests-are-angular-js-1-x-ngroute)

it would be better if someone help me to understand on how to setup NodeJs+angularjs1.x [ngRoute -] i just want to load external data

i've searched lot in google but results show only MEAN stack. but i dont want to get into depth for the first time. i just want learn step by step.

Thanks for helping me

Comment: Sorry but this is off-topic. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask carefully before asking.

Comment: instead mentioning this as "off-topic, useless, stupid, silly". why don't you help.? yeah already know about how to ask question in SO. that's why i mention my previous question's link here. but no one help. then what should i do.?

Comment: A link to previous question isn't a constructive question itself and thus is off-topic. A vague request for help is off-topic. Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking.  You asked the question only *3 hours ago*. Please, be patient. This is voluntary community. If you need immediate and full answer, there are paid services for this. If you won't get an answer you're looking for, you can earn some reputation by then and spare it on a bounty. The question will be eligible for bounty in 2 days.